# ERROR: gcloud crashed (MultiError): One or more errors occurred: MaxRetrialsException:

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

I have created a chatbot using React as frontend and in the backend I have used the `mistral-7b-instruct` model, this is my project structure:
[project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hBC9E.png)

However, after the final step completes I get the following error:

`ERROR: gcloud crashed (MultiError): One or more errors occurred: MaxRetrialsException: last_result=(None, (<class 'httplib2.python3.httplib2.error.ServerNotFoundError'>, ServerNotFoundError('Unable to find the server at storage.googleapis.com'), <traceback object at 0x00000235C0307100>)), last_retrial=3, time_passed_ms=1048388,time_to_wait=0`

I am running Win11, and python 3.10

I am using GCP for the same and I am following these steps:

1. `npm run build` - to ensure that the app is ready for deployment.
2. `gcloud init` - initialized the Google Cloud SDK.
3. `gcloud app deploy`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.